# Establish HTTPS connection with certificate on wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

How can I establish a HTTPS connection using a custom certificate on the windows phone to establish that connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone only accepts certificates that are root signed by a limited number of recognized providers; if what you have is a self-signed certificate, you won't be able to use it on Windows Phone...

Comment: Ok. Thanks pedro! Do you have any example on how to do that?